# How to print only first value of idx, val

Tags: python, list

I'm using python to create a function which takes information and prints it out accordingly.

Part of what I'm doing is that trying to print the first value in the 'row' as it contains the name.

I know that using the below will print me all the values in the row, but how do I specify just the first value?

```
for idx, val in enumerate(row):
                        print("%s" % (val))
```

Comment: `print(row[0])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for idx, val in enumerate(row):
    if idx == 0:
        print("%s" % (val))
```

Edit1:
Explanation->
when you use 'enumerate', it allows you to loop through each item and also be provided the index (where you are at) in each loop. Your variable idx will start at 0 and increment up in value by 1 each time you loop (until you run out of values to loop through in variable 'row). Since you are looking to print the first value, simply put a conditional if statement to see if idx is zero, if it is, print the current value (val).

Comment: Can you describe your solution? It may help others to understand.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! This is great for future use